# What's the role of BEC in superfluidity?

Tags: superfluidity, low-temperature-physics, bose-einstein-condensate

I'm writing about superfluid $^4$He. I've seen in some places that the transition to superfluid is attributed to Bose-Einstein condensation, but then in others that this model needs a massive amount of adaptation to account for the more strongly interacting particles in a fluid as opposed to in a gas.

So is BEC useful in any way when looking at superfluids? Is it worth discussing or is it just useless below the lambda point?